# multiple arrays in codeigniter session

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to get multiple arrays in a CodeIgniter session:

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('products')){
  $outerarray = array(
  $array = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'quantity' => 1
            ));
  array_push($outerarray, $this->session->userdata('products'));
  $data['products'] = $outerarray;
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
} else {
  $data['products'] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'quantity' => 1
            );
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
```

The else part works fine, but when there is already an array in the session it will put it like this in the session:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } }
```

what i really want to see is this:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["quantity"]=> int(1) }
```

Is there a possibility to have only the content of the `$outerarray` in the session and not the whole `$outerarray` itself?

Comment: try this array_push($_SESSION['products'], $data);

Comment: `$this->session->set_userdata($data[0]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
$data = array('id' => 1, 'quantity' => 2);

if (isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
    array_push($_SESSION['products'], $data);
}
else {
    $_SESSION['products'] = array($data);
}
```